# How to implement pushwoosh on xdk (intel)

Tags: push-notification, cross-platform, intel-xdk, pushwoosh

I have followed all the steps suggested on the [Pushwoosh website](https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/android-additional-platforms/phonegapcordova-sdk-integration/) but I still get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pushNotification' of undefined`
Please help me!

### more information about my code:

1. "https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin.git"-> I Installed the Plugin source code
2. Whitelist *.pushwoosh.com domain in the config.xml file: ->I didn't do that because xdk
   should do it automatically

3.Register for push notifications: Add the following function to your javascript file, enter the correct Project Number and Pushwoosh App ID

```js
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     // Handler for .ready() call
   initPushwoosh();
   }
                     
 //push begin
  function initPushwoosh(){
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
 
    //set push notifications handler
    document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
        var title = event.notification.title;
        var userData = event.notification.userdata;
                                 
        if(typeof(userData) != "undefined") {
            console.warn('user data: ' + JSON.stringify(userData));
        }
                                     
        alert(title);
    });
 
    //initialize Pushwoosh with projectid: "GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID", appid : "PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID". This will trigger all pending push notifications on start.
    pushNotification.onDeviceReady({ projectid: "****", appid : "****" });
 
    //register for pushes
    pushNotification.registerDevice(
        function(status) {
            var pushToken = status;
            console.warn('push token: ' + pushToken);
        },
        function(status) {
            console.warn(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
        }
    );
}
  
  document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
    var title = event.notification.title;
    var userData = event.notification.userdata;
 
    console.warn('user data: ' + JSON.stringify(userData));
    alert(title);
});
  
  //push end
```

Comment: Please post you code.

Comment: whats steps did you take in the intel xdk? I successfuly using this plugin in intel xdk

Comment: I have added more informaton  in my post. Did I forget something?

Comment: I used a **web-plugin** as a **third party plugin**
I have a question to you: can you tell me what steps you've used, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if window.plugins.pushNotification is not null or undefined.

If it is null (or undefined), make sure your reference plugin correctly in config.xml ("phonegap plugin add" command should do everything for you automatically).

If you provide more information, I could improve the answer.

Comment: I did what you said but I still have the same error.
Here is my check code:
<pre> var pushNotification; 
 if((window.plugins.pushNotification == null) || (typeof window.plugins.pushNotification =="undefined")){
  alert('make sure your reference plugin correctly in config.xml');
   }else{
    alert('ok');
pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
   }<code>

Comment: so which alert do you see?

Comment: this one: **window.alert('make sure your reference plugin correctly in config.xml')**
The system can not go into the if-statement.

Comment: How did you add your plugin to the project? It looks like the reference is missing from config.xml.

Comment: 1.step: I have clicked on XDK PROJECTS
2.step: The current name of the poject is clicked
3.step: On the right side I've chosen **plugins and permissions** and then **third-party-plugins** 
4.step:  a click on the **Get plugin from the web** button
5.step:  name: **pushNotification**, plugin ID: **com.pushwoosh.plugins.pushwoosh**, repo url: **https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-PhoneGap-3.0-plugin.git**
6.step: a click on the **import** button

Comment: Are you trying this in Emulator? Please note as per XDK spec Emulator and App Preview does not work with 3rd party plugins. You have to actually build the app and install it on a real device to test.

Comment: I have tested it on real device too... 
**/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin.git** I've seen xdk supports **phonegap 2.9**...maybe there is the error?!

Comment: I have added **<script src="xhr.js"></script>** below **<script src="intelxdk.js"></script>** in my index.html and it works....**Thanks for your support**